# Is path coverage stronger than condition coverage?

Tags: testing, unit-testing, test-coverage

I have encountered (even in literature) two contradicting opinions related to path vs condition coverage (not branch or edge!). Some say Path coverage is stronger than the condition coverage, some say the opposite.

Having code like this:

```
If(X<0 OR X>100)
   DoStuff();
```

*Path coverage* - 1 test case is needed to cover the path. With X=-1, the second expression will not be tested and possible bug will be missed.
*Condition coverage* - test cases X=-1 and X=100 are needed to test both conditions.

Am I missing something or condition coverage is really stronger than path coverage?

**Condition coverage (ISTQB):**

> **Our next level of coverage is called condition coverage. The basic concept is that, when a decision is made by a complex expression that eventually evaluates to TRUE or FALSE, we want to make sure that each atomic condition is tested both ways.**

*Practical Insight Into CMMI*

> Condition coverage measures the true and false outcome of each Boolean
>   subexpression.

**References:**

*Software Testing: Principles and Practices from Srinivasan Desikan,Gopalaswamy Ramesh:* page 61

> Condition coverage is a much stronger criteria than path coverage,
>   which in turns is a much stronger criteria than statement coverage.

Comment: According to every definition of "path coverage" I can find, *three* test cases would be necessary to fully cover the `if` block, one for each of the three possible execution paths. What definition are you using?

Comment: @Rogerio You are confusing the defition with condition coverage. If branches into 2 paths. In that example, you need the condition to be true to test the path) or false (to test the other path). Path coverage does not care about sub-expressions, it is what it is - path coverage.

Comment: @user970696 No. Any correct definition of path coverage cannot take into account the syntax of the programming language. The only thing in a method/routine that affects its number of paths is the occurrence of "branching points", aka "conditional branches". An "if" translates to a branching point, *just like* a short-circuit "and/or" operator. Wikipedia (at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) even says that "Short-circuit operators are, in effect, control structures". So, in that example, we have *two* branching points and *three* paths.

Comment: The example you give is also known as boundary testing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither one is "stronger" in the mathematical sense:

- Path coverage does not imply condition coverage, as illustrated by an example in your question
- Condition coverage does not imply path coverage, as illustrated by your comment (condition `IF(A&&B)` with pairs `A=TRUE, B=FALSE` and `A=FALSE, B=TRUE`).

This means that claims that either side is somehow "stronger" would be invalid.

If you "upgrade" the condition coverage to [*modified condition/decision coverage*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Condition/Decision_Coverage), however, the answer would be "yes": MC/DC always implies covering the path, but covering the path may not necessarily imply even covering the condition, let alone MC/DC.

However, this does not imply that 100% MC/DC is always better than path coverage: the tradeoff is that it comes at much steeper "price" than a 100% path coverage due to the need to write more tests. Sometimes, a lot more. This has a potential of complicating the maintenance of your test suite.

I think it is a good idea to maintain a good balance between condition/decision coverage and path coverage by path-covering simple conditions (such as argument checks of the "null or empty" sort) and condition/decision-covering statements with complex business logic.

Comment: I would not say covering a condition always implies covering a path - e.g. IF(A&&B). You need two cases for 100% condition coverage - A=TRUE, B=FALSE and A=FALSE, B=TRUE. But both test cases results in FALSE, yet both subexpression were tested. This is solved by decision/condition coverage,

Comment: @user970696 Oops, I always thought that MC/DC *was* the condition coverage! I'm updating the answer for this.

Comment: Thanks. For "simple" condition coverage, do you still think it is stronger than path? Thanks again.

Comment: @user970696 I fixed the answer. I do not think that condition coverage is stronger or weaker than path coverage.

Comment: I don't think your first bullet point (or the same remark in the question) is correct; given 1 `if` statement, there's 2 paths, not 1.  You can enter it, or not.  For complete path coverage, you must test both.

Comment: @Izkata You are missing the point. The path coverage does not deal with subexpression and thus you can cover the path with only partial condition coverage. In the example, with X=-1 you execute the conditional path. WIth X=0 you would execute ELSE. But you need to test the subexpression X>100 as well.

Comment: There are *three* different paths over `if (x<0 or x>100) DoStuff()`. Full path coverage requires all paths to be fully executed, while full condition coverage "only" requires that each sub-expression (`x<0`, `x>100`, and the combined expression) be evaluated to both `true` and `false`. So, path coverage is stronger than condition coverage.

Comment: @Rogerio *Three* different paths exist only according to your own, personal, definition. According to the commonly accepted definition, however, each decision point creates a single fork in the path, meaning that there are exactly two paths through the code in question. You are welcome!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Please provide a link to your definition of path coverage. The one I use can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage, http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_Path_coverage_in_software_testing, http://www.bullseye.com/coverage.html, etc. They all basically say it is a metric that finds "whether each of the possible paths in a function were followed". Perhaps you are confused by the `or` operator in the example? Given that most (all?) programming languages use short circuiting, that is a separate "branching point", which implies a third path.

Comment: @Rogerio From the Wikipedia link: "Full path coverage, of the type described above, is usually impractical or impossible. Any module with a succession of n decisions in it can have up to 2^n paths within it". In the OP's code there is a single decision to make; the fact that the decision itself relies upon a composite expression, with or without short-circuiting, has no bearing on the number of paths through the code: there are still only two path through that conditional - one for when the entire condition is true, and another one for when it is false.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Your interpretation doesn't work in practice. Consider the following proof, with a slight modification to the example code. Say we want to test the method `int calc(int x) { if (x < 0 || x++ > 100) doStuff(); return x; }`. This obviously requires *three* tests, say: 1) calc(5) == 6, 2) calc(-1) == -1, and 3) calc(101) == 102. Tests 2 and 3 both execute `doStuff()`, but they differ in the output, since one returns `x` while the other returns `x+1`. This happens because there *are* three paths. Note the `x++` side effect doesn't change the number of paths.

Comment: @Rogerio Nowhere did I argued that the code required two tests instead of (at least) three, only that according to the commonly accepted definition of path coverage the code has only two paths, not three. The definition considers each branching point (i.e. an `if` statement or a loop header) a single path-altering point, no matter how complex its underlying condition might be. In fact, there lies the reason why path coverage is not as good as the condition/decision coverage.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight A "branching point" isn't merely an `if`. Any point in executable code where the execution flow can diverge is, *by definition*, a branching point. If you examine the low-level machine code (including for virtual machines such as JVM bytecode), you would see a "jump" instruction there. A "path" is nothing more, nothing less than a unique sequence of individual machine instructions or atomic fragments in source code, through which a function/method can be executed from entry to exit.

Comment: For another demonstration that we indeed have *three* paths, consider that `if (a || b) c(); else d();` can be rewritten as `if (a) c() else if (b) c(); else d();`, which contains two "ifs" and three separate conditionally-executed blocks. Translated to low-level machine code, these two are (potentially, depends on compiler) identical. In both cases, the behavior is exactly the same, requiring three tests to have all its (three) paths covered.

Comment: @Rogerio In the common definition of path coverage a "path" is defined in terms of lines of code, not in terms of execution paths. It leaves out the low level stuff on purpose, shielding the measure from implementation details. For example, in Objective C you can legally call methods on null objects: instead of an exception, you get the default value back. On the low level, doing that involves a conditional, but it's a single path as far as the path coverage is concerned. The fact that in practice testing that conditional is the right thing to do changes nothing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8316/discussion-between-rogerio-and-dasblinkenlight)

Comment: Actually, path coverage is the strongest, but it involves paths created by combination of individual predicates. E.g. for four IFs, there are 16 paths, while the other criteria address just coverage of individual IFs.

Answer (score 6):

Path coverage is strictly more complete than branch coverage.

[An example pulled from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity#Implications_for_Software_Testing):

> two properties of the cyclomatic complexity, M, for a specific module:
>
> - M is an upper bound for the number of test cases that are necessary to achieve a complete branch coverage.
> - M is a lower bound for the number of paths through the control flow graph (CFG).

```
if( c1() )
   f1();
else
   f2();

if( c2() )
   f3();
else
   f4();
```

> In this example, two test cases are sufficient to achieve a complete branch coverage, while four are necessary for complete path coverage. The cyclomatic complexity of the program is 3 (as the strongly connected graph for the program contains 9 edges, 7 nodes and 1 connected component) (9-7+1).
>
> [image: Cyclomatic complexity example]

However, as noted a little further down (bolding mine for emphasis):

> Unfortunately, **it is not always practical to test all possible paths through a program.** Considering the example above, each time an additional if-then-else statement is added, the number of possible paths doubles. As the program grew in this fashion, it would quickly reach the point where testing all of the paths was impractical.

**EDIT**

Okay, I think I see where @user970696 in the comments is coming from.  If I understand right, the answer is *still* strictly path coverage.  The only time you'll have a "special" result different from branch coverage is when there's functions being called in the conditional, which may or may not run due to short-circuiting.

But when that happens, they count as part of the path.

Take this, for example:

```
if (a() && b()):
   foo()
else:
   bar()
```

- Branch coverage has 2 cases:

  - (a() && b()) == True
  - (a() && b()) == False
- Conditional coverage has 3 cases:

  - a() == False
  - a() == True && b() == False
  - a() == True && b() == True
- Path coverage has the same 3 cases:

  - Path: a(), bar()
  - Path: a(), b(), bar()
  - Path: a(), b(), foo()

However, when you add in a second `if` statement, as mentioned above, the number of paths will multiply - while each individual `if` statement stays at the same complexity.

Comment: But we are not speaking about BRANCH but CONDITION coverage, which is not the same.

Comment: @user970696 Please remember that this from Wikipedia, and it is using branch consistently with its page on [branch (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_%28computer_science%29) which describes a branch as "A branch is sequence of code in a computer program which is conditionally executed depending on how the flow of control is altered at the branching point."  If you are using a different definition of branch and condition, you will need to remember to translate that in your head to what you think it is.

Comment: @user970696 In that case, what is condition coverage?  The [only reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage#Modified_condition.2Fdecision_coverage) I can find isn't strictly by that name, and is about single `if` statements, which again, is strictly less powerful than path coverage, because you'll check both results of the first `if` while ignoring the second, then both results of the second `if` while ignoring the first - but not how they interact (if I'm reading it right).

Comment: MichaelT: We are not speaking about branch coverage at all. We are speaking here about condition coverage which is something else - it measures the false and true outcomes of each boolean subexpression. It is term used everywhere in the literature. I will add some quotes to original question.

Comment: The principle of condition coverage is - unlike branch coverage - to test ALL subexpression in the condition, not just the overall outcome.

Comment: @user970696 certainly not at wikipedia where the example in the answer comes from.  See also [o'reilly](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/03/02/statement-branch-and-path-coverage-testing-in-java.html), [whitepaper](http://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals/air_software/cast/cast_papers/media/cast-10.pdf), [coding](http://www.codign.com/pathbranchcode.html), [hitex](http://www.hitex.com/index.php?id=branch-decision-coverage-c1), [ncover](http://www.ncover.com/support/docs/v3/best-practices/are-you-covered-measuring-the-quality-of-net-code-with-ncover/), etc...

Comment: MichaelT: Yes Wikipedia does not use it, but it not an authoritative source. Books on testing clearly distinct between these. While branch/decision evaluates whole condition, condition coverage makes sure each subexpression is evaluated, as I mentioned in the example code in the original post.

Comment: @MichaelIT You are referring to something else. CONDITION coverage cares about boolean subexpressions, which is different to BRANCH coverage which only cares about the outcome of the whole decision. I do remember being told the distinction on my CS/software engineering courses.

Comment: @user970696 See updated answer

Comment: @MichaelT, Izkata: I added the definition from ISTQB.

Comment: @Iztaka: I think for Path coverage, you do not consider subexpressions, only the final outcome. So it is still just 2 cases - TRUE and FALSE.

Comment: @user970696 No, subexpressions are definitely counted, as they may have further branches inside of them.

Comment: @Izkata: Just checked that, it is not like that. Path is only about combining the all paths in the code but it not including subexpression - that is condition coverage.

Comment: @Izkata See, a code with two IFs has 4 paths, no matter how many subexpreesions do the IFs have. It only considers the final outcome. Maybe misunderstandinf - subexpression is not a nested if. This IF has two subexpressions: IF(A>10 OR B==1) but outcome is just TRUE or FALSE. Not sure what you meant by further breanches,

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between condition coverage and path coverage is that condition coverage is local to some control structure (if, while, for, ...), whereas path coverage is global to the whole program and therefore includes all possible combinations of branches (not conditions).

On the local point of view, condition coverage is stronger.

On the global point of view, path coverage is stronger. So stronger that it is usually not achievable.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, neither

1. Path Coverage implies Condition Coverage NOR
2. Condition Coverage implies Path Coverage

There are very simple examples which proof that:

(1): Path Coverage doesn't imply Condition Coverage:

```
if (A and B) then
    some elementary statement(s)
end if
```

Path Coverage is provided by:

- `A = false`
- `A = true and B = true`

**But**: For Condition Coverage we require `A = true and B = false` as well.

(2): Condition Coverage doesn't imply Path Coverage:

```
if (A)
    some elementary statement(s)
end if
if (B)
    some (other) elementary statement(s)
end
```

Condition Coverage is provided by:

- `A = false and B = false`
- `A = true and B = true`

**But**: For Path Coverage we require `A = false and B = true` as well as `A = true and B = false`.

Answer (score 0):

Path coverage basically includes the coverage of the statements in the program that you have written.That is if the program contains the following lines of code as:
1. if(condition 1)
2.  then call a function;
3.  else
4.  call that function;
5.  call another function;
So if we now closely observe the code we will find that there are 5 statements in total and the two of those statements are actually conditions.
So a path coverage will start from the first path and will check if the condition is true. If not then it will switch to the else part and execute the statement 4 and 5.Thus in all the number of statements covered are 1,3,4,5.
Whereas in the condition coverage the if and the else part are checked only not the 5th statement i.e. only statements 1 and 3 are checked. But also note that if there were only conditions then here in this case path coverage=statement coverage.