# Is it possible to derive a test suite to achieve 100% path coverage?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, test-coverage

Here is an example with the function:

Examining this I believe that it is possible to achieve 100% path coverage.

My understanding of path coverage is that you need to design test cases such that all independent paths in the program are executed at least once.

Looking at the source code and simplified control flow graph I don't see any restrictions that wouldn't allow you to test every single pathway through having multiple test cases. Am I wrong in saying this?

Comment: Do you want to know if 100% path coverage is possible for your specific example? The answer is "yes", but you know it already, why don't you just write down the test cases and check it by yourself? We won't do this for you. Or do you want to know if 100% path coverage is possible for every function (or lets says, every reasonable  function in a real-world application)? That question cannot be clarified by your example, because it is far-too-specialized to be representative.

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for software engineers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective.

Comment: +1 Existing approaches to coverage report the percentage of code lines that are executed, and it's not too hard in most code bases to get to 100%. That's where measurement currently stops. 100% code line coverage does not imply all execution paths are covered. To be able to measure that with a standard `pytest` approach would be a meaningful and improved metric. This may be about ["condition coverage"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185869/is-path-coverage-stronger-than-condition-coverage) rather than path coverage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory? No. As that would be equivalent to solving the halting problem. You would need to enumerate infinite number of inputs to cover all the possible paths. Which is clearly impossible.

In practice? For some small, simple problems, yes, it is possible. Your example problem demonstrates it.

But for any bigger, real-life problem, it would be both difficult and expensive to do so. Once you start using 3rd party code, you will never know what possible paths the code can take there. And considering such method can have an infinite state as an input, it becomes equivalent to the halting problem.

The closes to this are formal methods of verification of software. But those are slow and expensive and only worth it in limited scenarios, where extreme reliability is necessary.

Comment: Actually a physical computer has a limited number of inputs it can achieve if we consider the input state constant.